# Alternative of silverlight object in Chrome in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, silverlight

I have Asp.net application where I am using Silverlight to show disgrams. Now only problem is Silverlight works on IE but I want to run that in Chrome.
Here is code

```
<asp:Silverlight ID="Silverlight1" runat="server" MinimumVersion="2.0.30523"  
 Source="~/SilverlightHTDiagram.xap"  Height="430px" Width="500px" 
 PluginBackground="White" > 
  </asp:Silverlight>
```

How Can I make it work in chrome ??

Or How can I convert it into something with minimal change to make it working chrome ?

Comment: How did you implement your diagram in Silverlight? If you used a diagram control, perhaps the designer of that control has made something similar for HTML/JavaScript. For example: https://forum.nwoods.com/t/converting-goxam-to-gojs/4577

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no easy way of doing this. If I were in your shoes, I would basically look for some good diagram libraries made for HTML5/JavaScript, and start to use those, which is in essence redoing all of the diagrams in a different language.

There are some blog posts on this on the internet, i.e. [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219370/From-Silverlight-To-HTML), but in all, Silverlight is dead as a browser plugin, it will not be supported by Microsoft, and will not work in any modern browsers, so HTML5/JavaScript is the way to stay future-proof.

Alternatively, you could re-use the XAML in your silverlight app to adopt it into a UWP app, or WPF if you prefer, however, in these days with people running various OS'es, that is probably not what you're after.

Comment: XAML reuse with UWP? That's almost impossible.